# Waiting for other AsyncTasks' finish in AsyncTask before processing onPostExecute

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm getting info from an URL and sending that info to multiple URLs. I'm running it on a "for" in `AsyncTask`, and at onPostExecute of first `AsyncTask`, I change a `TextView` and telling that "All is done" to user.

But the thing is even the children of `AsyncTask` is continuing to being executed, parent `AsyncTask` executes its `onPostExecute`. So I need to wait for them and I'm stuck about it.

So, I have two AsyncTask classes. That's the class I send to websites:

```
class SendTo extends AsyncTask <Object,Object,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... strings) {
        ....
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //update ui for gathered information
    }

}
```

That's the task which I get from websites:

```
class GetFrom extends AsyncTask <Object,Object,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... strings) {
        ....
        String param = anotherMagicalFunctionThatGivesParamToSend(strings[1]);
        for(i = 1; i < websites.length; i++){
            publishProgress(websites[i],param);
        }
        return "";
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(final Object... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        new SendTo().executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, values[1], values[0]);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //finish things
    }
}
```

Comment: AsyncTasks are asynchronous by nature, so it makes no sense to launch an AsyncTask from another AsyncTask and wait for it to complete. What you need to to is run the background task of the second AsyncTask synchronously from the first AsyncTask's doInBackGround() method. In your case that would be the list of SendTo() operations.
If you want to run 2 individual AsyncTasks in sequence, you can start them one after another and they will be run in sequence by default in API 11+.

Comment: if you have no thing to do after you send info to wesites then its better to run all those `network operations` in `doInBackground` of first `asyncTask` and you don't need 2nd `asyncTask`

Comment: @indramurari sorry for that, i've forgotten about it. yes, i'm also sending data to `ListView` from 2nd task.

Comment: @BladeCoder I need and dont wanna break the `multithreading`. I was tryig to get without a `multithreading` before `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` and it really slows me down.

Comment: @AlperÖzdemir run an infinite loop after 'for loop' in the first asynctask. Once your done with all the sendTo asyncTask then break it. You can use some flags. Not a very good way but can solve your problem.

Comment: give detail witch type of data you are getting outer asynctask and what you want to do from outer asyncTask

Comment: But in this particular case you don't want multithreading, if I understand well your first task just needs to wait for the second task and do nothing else in the meantime. So I suggest you merge both in a single AsyncTask or use the SERIAL_EXECUTOR only when needed.

Comment: @BladeCoder  I pretty need multithreading. I'm trying to get rid of single threading system. My code was single-threaded before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run following `for loop` inside `postExecute()` of `asyncTask` as it's anyway not useful running `thread` inside the `thread`.
2. Maintain one `global variable` which will have count of completed `asyncTasks` and will be incremented by 1 when each `asyncTask` will completes it's execution. i.e it will come into `postExecute`.
3. In Every `postExecute` check if that count is equal to number of websites. If that number will be equal to number of websites that basically means all of your data is successfully `synced` else it's still in process.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend use callback in this case.

Create an interface:

```
public interface MyCallback {
    public void readycallback(int index_thread);
}
```

First class:

```
    class SendTo extends AsyncTask <Object,Object,String>{
private    MyCallback cb;
private int i;
public SendTo(int i, MyCallback cb) {
this.cb = cb;
this.i = i;
}
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Object... strings) {
            ....
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
if (cb != null)
cb.readycallback(i);
            //update ui for gathered information
        }

    }
```

Second class:

```
      class GetFrom extends AsyncTask <Object,Object,String>{
            private boolean[] array_of_completed_tasks = new boolean[websites.length - 1];
                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(Object... strings) {
                    ....
                    String param = anotherMagicalFunctionThatGivesParamToSend(strings[1]);
                    for(i = 1; i < websites.length; i++){
                        publishProgress(websites[i],param);
                    }

        while(!checkIfAllThreadAreCompleted()) {
        //waiting all threads
//you can wait
try {
                    Thread.sleep(10L);// ten milliseconds
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
                    return "";
                }
                protected void onProgressUpdate(final Object... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    new SendTo(i, new MyCallback() {
            @Override
                public void readycallback(int index_thread) {

                //this is your ready callback
            array_of_completed_tasks[index_thread] = true;
                }


                   }).executeOnExecutor(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, values[1], values[0]);
                    }
        }
            private boolean checkIfAllThreadAreCompleted() {


       boolean ok = true;
        for(i = 0; i < array_of_completed_tasks.length; i++){
        ok = ok && array_of_completed_tasks[i];
                    }
        return ok;

                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    //finish things
                }
            }
```

Or use Threads for much better coding style. But I really think that using `AsyncTask` is very ugly methods is real projects.

Comment: Thanks for codes, at `cb(i)` line getting `Method call expected` error. Also I wonder how would it look like if I was using `Threads`.

Comment: @AlperÖzdemir , fixed

Comment: @AlperÖzdemir, accept if this is the correct answer

Comment: well komrade, the code looks brilliant but the fact is I couldn't put this into my code. So I solved it in different way and I'll look for usage of Threads instead of Asynchronous Tasks.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not a good idea to have one `AsyncTask` simply wait for other `AsyncTask`s to complete. It makes the code more complex and prevents using that thread in the pool while it's waiting.

If you can, it would be simpler that you launch all `AsyncTask`s in parallel and have them all call the same method in `onPostExecute()`. That method would then check if all the results of all the `AsyncTask`s have been posted and show "All is done" in that case.

If you really want to have one AsyncTask wait in `doInBackground()` for one or more other `AsyncTask`s to complete (effectively pausing that background thread), you can use standard Java synchronization mechanisms. I recommend using [`CountDownLatch`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html).

It's worth noting that synchronizing between background tasks is something that can be achieved quite easily with **RxJava** rather than using `AsyncTask` which has been designed for simple use cases.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I'll take a look. Well, I have a loop and I'm publishing urls from there, so if I'd using result it'd be kinda hard... Anyway, I'll try to run them in `onPostExecute` and report... Also I'm new to java so I don't know about that functions/libraries. I'll check them too.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass you TextView in child asyncTask and update its value in onPost method of child asynchTask .

Comment: Not actually. It's working parallel and if one of 50 tasks finish, it'll say "completed" but others will continue to be processed.

Comment: you can use a flag and update textview based on flag in last asynTask